# Apparmor Blocking Network Access to Docker Containers on Debian

Tags: docker, lxc, lxd, apparmor

I am running Docker inside an unprivileged LXD Debian container. Docker is working well, except that the networking is not working within Docker. I can't access my Docker containers using my server's public IP.

After intensive googling and testing the solutions posted on SO and other forums I found out that removing the AppArmor package solved everything. The containers were able to get internet access. So far, I am happy.

However, there's a concern in my mind. Is removing AppArmor a good solution?

Why in the first place AppArmor is blocking the Docker network? This didn't happen by default on Ubuntu LXD containers.

Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this https://askubuntu.chttps://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmorom/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor.

Comment: There could be security issues.